# Web API: How to properly use with MVC5 form population after Read?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api

I have to move a project from a purely controller based scenario to one utilizing web API.  There are currently a lot of views already intact whose forms are populated from the controller which calls an injected service object to get its data for edit (update) scenarios.

What is the recommended way to populate a form without using a purely AJAX and jQuery approach when the form loads?  Would there be a lost in efficiency by having the controller call the web API method?  It seems a little inefficient to have to write a bunch of functions that populate the form fields one line at a time.

Also, for the form, how would I differentiate between when a form would "POST" and when it would "PUT"?

Comment: This question is very vague and overly broad (contains a lot of open ended questions). Could you create a simpler smaller question listing the specific scenarios your talking about? As it stands I can't see how this question is answerable.

Comment: In a nutshell, I would like to know the recommended approach for handling crud operations between web api and mvc5 controllers.  Would you take the controller out of the equation and just use ajax and the view or would you still use the controller?  The biggest confusion for me at the moment is where the handling of form population should go?  An example outlining crud using mvc5 and web api would be great.

Comment: One thing you didn't specify is why you have to move from MVC to Web API? You can probably do all the work in MVC so please specify the exact reason, this might help us provide you with the right approach. Otherwise the question is just too generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I totally understand your question but I give it a shot =)...

The purpose of using a web api is to have the data separated or a separated data service. When you use a (server side) MVC Framework you send a view to the client which contains prepared HTML. When you call a web api you'll get only data in a certain (requested) format (xml, json, pdf, png).

How you structure your API heavily depends on your architecture and style... 
But you will use Ajax for your HTML client to retrieve the data... If you go this route you should also take a look at Frameworks like Ember.js, Angular.js or the ASP.NET SPA template because you will work with a lot of Javascript =)...

Remember that API's are made to be consumed. So the consumer / client is responsible for preparing the data from the api. The client can be a Single Page Application (HTML). It can also be another server which prepares a view (machine-to-machine communication). So for example query your API from within your controller in a MVC application (whether it makes sense depends on the use case).

Take a look at this book: Designing Evolvable Web APIs with ASP.NET (http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001708) this is a good read on that topic and explains alot background about hypermedia and rest and http.

HTH

Comment: This is close, especially the section about going the ajax route.  See, where I am confused is that it seems as if there is no other route that seems logical for most views, except an angular.js.  It seems as if other than having the controller to direct the user to a specific view, any other work crud-based would be relegated to web api.  Would this be a correct view of this scenario?

Comment: Is there a way to use web api and still utilize the asp.net mvc controller for items outside of routing views?

Comment: sure, this is the more common approach to have two endpoints. 1 for an API and 1 for the web interface. http://server/customers and http://server/api/customers. This can also be combined in one solution in VS and can share code

Comment: Gotcha.  So the web interface would utilize the controllers, while, phone, pad, etc. could utilize web api.

Comment: exactly! And with clear seperation of concerns you can reuse data access like repository and validation rules, etc

Comment: just be careful of mixing terms. both web api and mvc use controllers.

Comment: Hey what's up with the bounty? My answer helped since you marked it as answered?